# How to throw a type error during Typescript type checking

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings

I have 2 types that should never intersect. Is there a way to make the typechecker flag when they do? Ideally, I'd like to do this purely in the types world without declaring any redundant variables.

**Example:**

```
type A = 1 | 2 // Must be different from B
type B_OK = 3
type B_FAIL = 2 | 3

// What I want (pseudo Typescript)
type AssertDifferent<X,Y> = Extract<X,Y> extends never ? any : fail // Fail if the types intersect

// Expected result (pseudo Typescript)
AssertDifferent<A,B_OK> // TS is happy
AssertDifferent<A,B_FAIL> // Fails type check
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet is to make your conditional type return true or false, and then try to assign `true` to the result. Like so:

```js
type A = 1 | 2 // Must be different from B
type B_OK = 3
type B_FAIL = 2 | 3

type AssertTrue<T extends true> = T;

type IsDifferent<X,Y> = Extract<X,Y> extends never ? true : false

type result1 = AssertTrue<IsDifferent<A, B_OK>>; // OK
type result2 = AssertTrue<IsDifferent<A, B_FAIL>>; // Error
```

You can use the new [`@ts-expect-error` comments](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-9.html#-ts-expect-error-comments) feature in version 3.9 on the second line to enforce that the error always throws.

Comment: Thanks! That's a viable solution; I have updated my answer to include the fact that I'd like to do this purely in the world of types, without declaring any redundant variables. If that's not possible, what you're suggesting definitely makes sense. Alternatively, I guess I can just do
`const result: Extract<X,Y> = null as never` without the intermediate type.

Comment: Fair enough @SquattingSlavInTracksuit - I did some fiddling and edited it, it's now a purely type-based solution.